# Can you call a variable in a method in another class?

Tags: java, class, methods, hashmap, zoo

Hi I'm new to prgramming, and currently doing a project in java.

I'm doing a simulation of a zoo, where animals eat specific foods and after consumption, they will gain a specific amount of health, as well as produce a specific amount of waste.

In order to do this, food has to be stored in a FoodStore class in a HashMap. In order to do this, I had created a a separate class called food, and created methods with their health and waste properties:

```
public class Food {

public int healthAdd;
public int wasteProd;

public Food hay(){
    healthAdd = +1;
    wasteProd =4;
    return null;
}
```

However, when I feed the animals I have to show that they have now gained new health points and have produced waste.

So i was wondering if it was possible to access the variables that I have initialized in, for example, the healthAdd & wasteProd in the "hay" method of the FoodClass in another class?

Sorry if this seems long winded :)

Comment: You can't call variables. You can only call methods. Those methods can access the variables in the object on which you called the method... Does that give you any ideas?

Comment: What does *"calling a variable"* mean?  Do you mean "can you access a variable used in another method?"

Comment: you can access them with the help instance of the Food class instance as you have declared them `public`.

Comment: @scottb yes thats what I meant, sorry for not being clear

Comment: @Laurenth can you elaborate how we can call method variables from another class

Comment: Can you please note that you have been already told twice that you don't call variables.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Java can be of two broad types.  You can have *"instance variables"* and you can have *"local variables"* (there are also static variables which I won't discuss).

Local variables are defined inside methods or inside curly braces and live only as long as the defined scope is active.  In other words, if a local variable is defined inside braces, it ceases to exist as soon as execution exits those braces.

Instance variables are defined inside a `class` definition but outside of any methods or other curly braces.  Those variables live for as long as the corresponding instance of that class lives.

For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int myInstanceVar1 = 0; // lives for as long as this MyClass
                                   // instance exists

    public MyClass() {   // Constructor for MyClass instances

        int myLocalVar1 = 0; // lives only during the constructor invocation
        :
        :
    }
    :
    :
}
```

In the snippet above, you would be able to access the `myInstanceVar1` field on any `MyClass` object that wasn't `null`.  The instance field exists for as long as the object does.

You would not, however, be able to access `myLocalVar1` because it only exists during the time at which the constructor is executing.  After the constructor has finished, the local variable falls out of scope and is no longer available anywhere in your program.